# How to send XML file from AEM DAM to InDesign server?

Tags: aem, adobe-indesign, indesign-server

I'm creating XML file pragmatically in AEM DAM using Java. I want send this created XML file to Adobe INDesign server automatically. And I want to import this XML file in InDesign server.

1) How can I send created XML file to InDesign server automatically after file creation in AEM DAM?

2) How can I integrate AEM DAM with InDesign server?

Please help me. I'm new with AEM and InDesign server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AEM has RESTful API. You can call it from an app you have to write and pull the XML you need and save it in a location where InDesign Server can access it.

The same app can make a SOAP call to InDesign Server to run an InDesign Script to process it and produce the output.

App could be any language you are familiar with, e.g node.js or bash/cmd batch file, provided it supports curl or similar

You can try to look at Zapier to skip the app creation.

There is no ready made integration, as far as I know, but if it is too much for you to developer you can hire a developer(s) who can help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm creating XML file using Java API and writing some content in created XML file. And want to send this file InDesign server. Is it possible send it using AEM Workflow?

Comment: If you are using Java, why you don't call InDesign Server from your Java app? You can do a SOAP request to InDesign and pass XML as a Parameter to the script, although on my experience it was slow for the large XML files.

Comment: Sorry, I am not a Java developer. SO is better dealing with specific problems and I do not think there will be something ready-made.

Comment: @Loic Thank you for your response. Please, can you share link with me of sample code. I googled for it but didn't get.

Comment: AEM Assets has InDesign server integration. Have you looked into that?  https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/assets/using/indesign.html